# Can a Magnet power a fan for a wind and electricity output?

Tags: schematics, electromagnetism, diagram

can it really be possible to power a ceiling fan with the use of magnets and could give you a wind and electricity output? how to do it? (For Remote Areas Without Electricity).

Comment: This is commonly done when camping, or on remote construction sites without power. Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-ehwxV4nf0) showing what is inside a large generator, and how it works.

Comment: thanks that make me understand a little bit but it's kinda big  i'm thinking about a ceiling fan or a wall fan to start-up.. ..just smalller ones :)

Comment: I think what you are asking is. Can you turn a ceiling fan into a wind powered generator? Technically yes if the motor is an induction motor. But the bearings will be designed for horizontal not vertical load so and it will not be designed for outdoor use. so you would need to mount the blades on an elbow/right angle gear and a long shaft that projected outside a weatherproof housing. But don't expect high efficiency..

Comment: @rdtsc - if you need a ceiling fan when you're camping, I think the term is glamping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magnet itself is not a source of energy. Electricity could be induced by moving a wire/coil in a magnetic field or moving magnetic field around the wire/coil. This tool are called a generator. Generator does not actually create electrical energy. Instead, it uses the mechanical energy supplied to it to force the movement. Typical generator uses the engine as source of the input mechanical energy to the generator. Generator engines operate on a variety of fuels such as gasoline, propane (in liquefied or gaseous form), or natural gas.

You can convert a table fan into generator. Look at this [instructables forum](http://www.instructables.com/answers/How-can-I-convert-an-AC-motor-to-a-generator/) and [this](http://www.thedoityourselfworld.com/table-fan-generator.php) reference. However, it is not an easy task.

Answer (score 0):

you can power a fan using magnet, but then you have to do a lot of work moving the magnet repeatedly. That is what a power generator does. Simplest wiring would be a wire and a magnet. You move the magnet repeatedly above that wire, and you get a tiny bit of electricity, mill-watt in precise sense. In practice, you need a powerful motor and a power source, such as a water fall to turn the motor to get electricity. last but the least, there is few magnet inside a motor.